# MySQL cursor is fetching the only first record multiple times

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

My Stored Procedure is like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `kiosk_pro`.`setTimeAdjustForNext`(tokenno int,cdate date)
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN

        declare lo_SNO int;

        declare lo_TokenNo int;


        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE ;

       Declare mycur Cursor for( select  SNO  from kiosk_token_generation  where TokenDate=cdate and  TokenNo >= tokenno order by TokenNo );
              DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;
       open mycur;

        time_loop :LOOP 

              FETCH mycur into lo_SNO;

             if done then 
                 close mycur;  
                  leave time_loop;
             end if;

            select lo_SNO ;

           end loop time_loop;


    END$$
```

Actually my table having 3 records 1,2,3 in SNO column and 1,2,3 in
TokenNo column, i'm calling above stored procedure by passing `date
='2014-02-22'` and `tokenno=1`, but it's returning 1 value three times.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your SP work fine

Maybe you have another SP in a different DB

```
create table kiosk_token_generation (SNO  int, TokenNo int, TokenDate datetime);
INSERT INTO kiosk_token_generation (SNO, TokenNo, TokenDate) VALUES (1,1,'2014-02-22');
INSERT INTO kiosk_token_generation (SNO, TokenNo, TokenDate) VALUES (2,2,'2014-02-22');
INSERT INTO kiosk_token_generation (SNO, TokenNo, TokenDate) VALUES (3,3,'2014-02-22');



DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE setTimeAdjustForNext(tokenno int,cdate date)
    BEGIN
       declare lo_SNO int;
       declare lo_TokenNo int;
       DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
       Declare mycur Cursor for( select  SNO  from kiosk_token_generation  where TokenDate=cdate and  TokenNo >= tokenno order by TokenNo );
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;
       open mycur;
       time_loop :LOOP
              FETCH mycur into lo_SNO;
             if done then
                 close mycur;
                 leave time_loop;
             end if;
            select lo_SNO ;
           end loop time_loop;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;






select  SNO  from kiosk_token_generation  where TokenDate='2014-02-22' and  TokenNo >= 1 order by TokenNo

CALL setTimeAdjustForNext (1, '2014-02-22');
```

Comment: instead of SNO in cursor if we take TokenNo then its not working properly